# Outer join with mandatory chain

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

Imagine I have this data

people -> address changes -> address change reasons

I want details of all people
I also want to know if they have ever changed address because of fire. So I don't want to know what the reasons are but if they have changed address for 1 single reason.

Each person could possibly have multiple address change reasons

so I have

```
SELECT people.*
CASE WHEN add_change.reason_id is not NULL THEN
  'Y'
 ELSE 
  'N'
 END as been_fire
from people
left outer join add_change ON  person.id = add_change.person
left outer join add_change_reason ON add_change.reason_id = add_change_reason.id  AND add_change_reason.text = 'FIRE'
```

but this returns multiple rows per person if they have many address changes.

I can't just use

```
left outer join add_change ON add_change.person = person.id AND add_change.reason_id = 5
```

as this isn't fixed data.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  You seem to want the change reason, and then you complain that multiple reasons result in multiple rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff There is no sample data as this isn't real data, just a simple example. So i am sure you can imagine how these tables are designed by my example SQL and overly simplistic ERD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `exists`:

```
SELECT p.*,
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM add_change ac JOIN
                               add_change_reason acr
                               ON ac.reason_id = acr.id 
NVL(address_change.reason,'N')
                          WHERE p.id = ac.person AND
                                acr.text = 'FIRE'
                         )
             THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N'
        END) as has_fire_address_change
from people p;
```

Note that this changes the flag to `'Y'` and `'N'`, which is what the description of your problem suggests that you want.

Comment: yes I do actually have a case returning Y and N in the real select. (which I now have in the question here)

Comment: I am using this solution now, but not accepting it as that isn't good form in the first 24 hours

Answer (score 1):

You could do a left join to a derived table that only returns person IDs that do have the change reason 'FIRE':

```
SELECT p.*
       CASE WHEN cr.person IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END as been_fire
from people
  left join (
    select ac.person
    from add_change ac
    where exists (select *
                  from add_change_reason acr 
                  where acr.id  = ac.reason_id 
                    AND acr.text = 'FIRE')
  ) cr on cr.person = p.id
```